# Counting the number of complete genes in a text file in C

Tags: c, count, counter

I want to count the number of genes from a text file using the C language, a triplet is a set of 3 letters.
gene consists of a sequence of triplets which contains a beginning and an end.

*beginning of the gene:*  ATG

*end of the gene:*  TAA, TGA or TAG

a gene is considered valid if at least one triplet between the beginning and end, for example TAA ATG, is not a valid gene

example of text file, the text file can have multiple lines

> **ATG** *GCA TAT ATG TGG AAG* **TAA** GTT GTA **ATG** *CAC GAT GGC AAC GGC GGC* **TAG**
>   CCA ATG AAA

This example contains two genes

I tried it so far, do not know how to find the beginning and then the end.

```
 int Count (char *file) {   
    FILE *ptr = NULL;   
    int count = 0;  

    char *start = "ATG";
    char *end = "TAA"; // miss TGA, TAG

    char chr;
    int occur, i;

    ptr = fopen(filename, "r");  //open text file

        if (ptr == NULL)
            return -1;

    chr = fgetc(ptr);
    while(chr != EOF){

             if(ch == start[0]){                 
                  for(i=1; i< StrLen(start); i++){
                    chr = fgetc(ptr);

                       if(chr == EOF){
                            occur = 0;
                            break;
                       }
                       else if(chr != start[i]){
                            chr = fgetc(ptr);
                            occur = 0;
                            break;
                       }
                       else
                            occur = 1;
                  }   

                  if(occur == 1){
                        count++;
                  }

             } else{
                chr = fgetc(ptr);
             }              
        }

    if (!feof(ptr)){
        return -1;
    }
    fclose(ptr);

    return count;
}

int StrLen(char *word){
 int i = 0;
 char c = word[0];
 while(c != '\0'){
  i++;
  c = word[i];
 }
 return i;
}
```

Help me Please! :)

Comment: Please dont misunderstand stackoverflow as "DoMyWork".  start with reading a file in c and moving forward and ask the problems u face while writing the code.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Seems like it would be a trivial regular expression. Try that approach, and come back if you have trouble getting the regex to work.

Comment: sorry, i put the code i have so far, i do not know how to find the end of the gene after the beginning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking at your problem from a higher level. You want to find genes consisting of a sequence of triplets. For that you must read triplets and test wether it is the start or end of a gene or something in between.

So, this could look like this:

```
char triplet[4];
while (read_triplet(fp, triplet)) {
    if (is_beginning(triplet)) {
        /* handle beginning */
    } else if (is_end(triplet)) {
        /* handle end of gene */
    } else {
        /* is between */
    }
}
```

and then define functions for triplet handling:

```
int read_triplet(FILE *fp, char *triplet) { /* ... */ }
int is_beginning(const char *triplet) { return strcmp(triplet, "ATG") == 0; }
int is_end(const char *triplet)
{
    if (strcmp(triplet, "TAA") == 0)
        return 1;

    if (strcmp(triplet, "TGA") == 0)
        return 1;

    if (strcmp(triplet, "TAG") == 0)
        return 1;

    /* No, it's not an end triplet */
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps for a start.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to create a scanner using flex, and let the scanner do the work. Take a look at [dinosaur.compilertools.net](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/) and [FLEX](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/flex/index.html). There's a bunch of old-school **domain specific language** tools which help to generate code for c/c++ to deal with grammar, syntax and parsing of text sequences. You just use the generated code from within your c program.
As a side note: you should probably use `perl` for this if your requirements allow for it, since it is tailored for that kind of tasks.